# HaskellにてGraphics.Glossを用いてウィンドウを表示させようとしたところ、エラーが出ました。

Tags: haskell

[この記事のコメント欄](https://qiita.com/lotz/items/eb73e62a64bc208c2dd6)にある通り、freeglut.dllをglut32.dllにリネームし、System32以下に置きましたが、エラー"user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)"が出ています。置く場所を間違えているのでしょうか？

[image: 実行時エラー]

Comment: exe ファイルと同じフォルダーに dll ファイルを配置してみても結果は同じでしょうか？

Comment: @岡本和樹 「コンパイル済みの状態でMain.exeがあるフォルダにglut32.dllを置いてMain.exeを実行」する場合と、「glut32.dllをMain.exeがあるフォルダに置いてコンパイルし、Main.exeを実行」する場合を試しましたが、同じエラーが出ました。